# What is AUTOSAR? Is it a file structure?

Tags: embedded-systems

I've gone through [AUTOSAR Layered Software Architecture](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-3/AUTOSAR_EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture.pdf) and understood that it is something like a file structure in which it is defined to have all the hardware abstraction in one directory and called as MCAL, and so on. Am I correct? Does a proper File Structure make a project AUTOSAR Compliant?

If it is a file structure then what should be used as it's build system? shall we use gnu-make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Autosar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOSAR) is a standardization initiative for software architecture in the automotive industry, and more precisely in the field of [Electronic Control Units](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_control_unit), which are all theses computing devices involved in the subsystems of a car (e.g. engine, brakes, transmission, etc...).

A reference architecture is not a file format: it‘s primarily a specification. It describes how the software is to be structured, what are the  responibilities, functions, or quality attributes expected from the different software components involved. It can also specify some technological building blocks to be used and specify sole common APIs.

The aim of such an architecture is to guarantee interoperability between sub-systems or even parts, which are designed and produced by different suppliers.

Comment: so if I organize my code as modules specified in the specification according to their functions, will my code be AUTOSAR compliant?
Sorry If I understood it in a wrong way. Can you suggest some starting point for me to learn about AUTOSAR from scratch. I need to work on Software Development for ECU's soon.

Comment: @KartheekAssk Imagine you sit in a prototype of a revolutionary self-driving car. You are told that the software is AUTOSAR compliant: would you be reinsured about the quality of the  software if it would only about believing in good faith that the developpers organised the code as they understood from reading a spec found on the internet?  AUTOSAR is a comprehensive standard.  THe layered architecture aim to reduce dependency between components in case of change, the key being to separate hardware dependent and hardware independent parts.  (...)

Comment: @KartheekAssk but this is only one aspect.  You have also API definition, you have coding standards,  you have foundation standards, and there are also compliance tests, not to speak about a development process.  It's a very comprehensive standard.  So the best would be to find some book about the subject.